# Create key value pair dict for each new line

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

QI have a data frame of 4 columns. I need to create a {key: value} dictionary for 2 of those columns where this {key: value} pair should be created for each separate line in the data frame. Please refer to the example below:

df>>

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  9  8  7  6
```

Expected output>>

```
   a  b  c  d  new-column
0  1  2  3  4  {a:1, b:2}
1  9  8  7  6  {a:9, b:8}
```

Comment: Your expected output is not clear. Can you format that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_dict`, craft a Series and `join` to the original DataFrame:

```
df2 = df.join(pd.Series(df[['a','b']].to_dict('index'), name='new_column'))
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d        new_column
0  1  2  3  4  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
1  9  8  7  6  {'a': 9, 'b': 8}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the values of returned dictionary of `to_dict('index')` to new column

```py
df['new-column'] = df[['a','b']].to_dict('index').values()
```

```
print(df)

   a  b  c  d        new-column
0  1  2  3  4  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
1  9  8  7  6  {'a': 9, 'b': 8}
```